# how to show bootstrap popover as selectable dropdown?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to show the bootstrap popover on hover. In popover content i have list action items. When i levave the element which i used to show the popver its getting disappeared. I want it to dispaly until i'm on the popover.

is it posible?

```
<a href="#" class="btn   btn-info" data-toggle="popover" data-content="hello" data-title="Welcome" data-placement="left"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i> Goto</a>
```

the Js is

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
      plcement:"left",
      title:"Heloo",
      content:"Welcome"
    });
```

How to have the popover remains present until i'm leaving from the popover content?

Answer (score 2):

Set the popover trigger, and then use a template in the popover that will hide itself when mouseout occurs...

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    trigger: 'manual',
    animate: false,
    html: true,
    placement: 'left',
    template: '<div class="popover" onmouseover="$(this).mouseleave(function() {$(this).hide(); });"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'

}).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() ;
}).mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).popover('show');
});
```

## [Bootply](http://bootply.com/98529)

Comment: For some reason, if I open the Bootply example in [Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/UWPtKZdy50) it works as advertised. However, if I open it in the Codeply _preview_ (external window - pop-up) – I can still select the tooltip text, but on right click it disappears.

This also happens when I try to replicate the example (the tool-tip window disappears) on right click.